# SvelteKit server loaded data shows on sources/index on chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sveltekit, pocketbase

I'm building a simple web app that uses self-hosted Pocketbase on backend, and SvelteKit as a meta framework.

I just noticed my server loaded data's are being shown in browser's sources/index file.

Here is my code on +page.server.js:

```
import { error } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import { serializeNonPOJOs } from "$lib/server/setting.js";

export const load = ({ locals, setHeaders }) => {
    setHeaders({
        'Cache-Control': `max-age=0, s-maxage=60`,
    })
    const getTopic = async () => {
        try {
            const topic = serializeNonPOJOs(
                await locals.pb.collection("topic").getFullList(undefined,{
                    sort: '-created'
                }),
            );
            return topic;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error:", err);
            throw error(err.status, err.message);
        }
    };
    return {
        topic: getTopic(),
    };
};
```

And in my +page.svelte file, I called page data as `export let data`

Also i'm using server hooks to handle the request:

```
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';
import { serializeNonPOJOs } from '$lib/server/setting';
import {POCKETBASE_URL} from '$env/static/private';

export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    event.locals.pb = new PocketBase(POCKETBASE_URL);
    event.locals.pb.authStore.loadFromCookie(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');

    try {
        if (event.locals.pb.authStore.isValid) {
            await event.locals.pb.collection('users').authRefresh();
            event.locals.user = serializeNonPOJOs(event.locals.pb.authStore.model);
        }
    } catch (_) {
        event.locals.pb.authStore.clear();
        event.locals.user = undefined;
    }

    const response = await resolve(event);
    response.headers.set('set-cookie', event.locals.pb.authStore.exportToCookie({ secure: false, 'max=-age': 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 }));

    return response;
};
```

I don't know if this a bug or feature or maybe i'm doing something wrong

I tried to not calling url from .env but instead just putting db address in there, for example:

```
export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    event.locals.pb = new PocketBase(****.com;
    event.locals.pb.authStore.loadFromCookie(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
```

EDIT-
My main concern is you can see all registered users email and phone number and other sensitive information. I can set the rules to list/search is off but i don't think that's the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

When SvelteKit builds up a page it does a fetch for the data used in that page.

However for your very first page all the html is already created, but SvelteKit still has to attach all kind of event listeners and reactivity to it, this process is called "hydration", during hydration SvelteKit will act is if you just navigated to this page. This would result in a new fetch for the data, which is a waste, to counter this SvelteKit will during server side rendering add the data object to your page and use that instead of fetching new data, this is the data you see here.

Note that all this means is that when navigating to this page, Svelte does a fetch for this data and therefore it will also be available in the network tab for a user wanting to look at it.

The solution is to ensure only the data you want to be visible to the client is actually send to the client, this process is often called "sanitizing" but goes by other names as well.

In your specific you would have something like this:

```js
export const load = () => {
  const data = getTopic();
  const topic = {
    title: data.title;
  }
  return {
   topic
  }
}
```